# Exclude certain env vars from artifactory publish

Tags: maven, gradle, publish, artifactory

I have a Gradle build script which puts some artifacts in Artifactory. I am passing the Artifactory credentials as environment variables (windows only shop). Is there any way to control that certain enviromental variables DO NOT get published by the clientConfig.setIncludeEnvVars? Obviously, I want to hide those Artifactory credentials. 
I have tried some Ant-style exclude patterns, but it either doesn't work, or I have some syntax problem:

```
clientConfig.setIncludeEnvVars(true, excludes: ['*PASS*'])
```

How the plugin is configured in the script:

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'maven-~~~'
            username = System.env.ARTIFACTORY_USER ? System.env.ARTIFACTORY_USER : ${artifactory_user}
            password = System.env.ARTIFACTORY_PASS ? System.env.ARTIFACTORY_PASS : ${artifactory_password}
            maven = true
            defaults {
                publications('mavenJava')
                publishArtifacts = true
                publishBuildInfo = true
                publishPom = true
                publishIvy = false
            }
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'maven-d~~~'
            username = System.env.ARTIFACTORY_USER ? System.env.ARTIFACTORY_USER : ${artifactory_user}
            password = System.env.ARTIFACTORY_PASS ? System.env.ARTIFACTORY_PASS : ${artifactory_password}
            maven = true
        }
    }
    clientConfig.setIncludeEnvVars(false) // caution: true exposes passwords which are envs!
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clientConfig.setIncludeEnvVars()` accepts a boolean values and control whether to include the env vars as part of the build info.

You should use either:

```
clientConfig.setEnvVarsExcludePatterns('*password*,*secret*')
```

or

```
clientConfig.setEnvVarsIncludePatterns('*not-secret*')
```

Both methods accepts a string which contains a comma delimited set of patterns. The patterns use star (*) as a wildcard.

Comment: Awesome! That's what I needed to know about, Thanks! - Also, if you happen to have a link to the documentation which describes the rest of the clientconfig features, that would be great to see.

Comment: It can now be found in the Gradle Artifactory plugin [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin). Was missing before.